# Array sort not working on Android Phone but does in emulator and AIR

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, sorting, cordova

I have a strange one (or at least it's beyond me as a novice programmer).

I have a javascript app I wrote some time ago for use with Adobe AIR that gathers some login/logout data from a sever and then displays it sorted by login name on the screen.

The data is received in timestamp chronological order ; for example here are the first three lines of the reterned data that I then parse into my array. The line format is timestamp, name, current status, last status change

```
Wed 1/18/2012 at 2:06 pm, Tanya, offline, Wed 1/18/2012 at 12:04 pm
Wed 1/18/2012 at 2:15 pm, Trav, offline, Wed 1/18/2012 at 2:05 pm
Wed 1/18/2012 at 2:22 pm, Trav, online, Wed 1/18/2012 at 2:15 pm
```

I recently revised the app so I could port it on mobile devices.
Note that I am using PhoneGap Build to build my mobile apps as I don't have enough knowledge to try to do it myself with SDKs so I'm not sure if this also plays a part in the issue.

When I run my AIR app or the mobile version in the Android emulator my output is grouped by Name and then the login/logout details are chronological within the name.

BUT - When I run my App on my mobile device (HTC Desire HD) the output is still grouped by Name, but the data under each name is no longer in chronologial order for some reason and seems quite random in order.

The key bits of code are below;

```
function byName (a, b) {return a[0] == b[0] ? 0 : a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : 1}  


var HistoryArr = new Array();
z = 0;
for (var i = 2; i < myArr.length - 1; i += 4) {
   HistoryArr[z] = new Array(myArr[i+1], myArr[i], myArr[i + 2], myArr[i + 3]);
   z++;
}

HistoryArr.sort(byName);
```

I'm not sure if I should be doing the sorting a different way, but what confuses me is that it works fine in AIR and the android emulator just not on the phone.

So any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to make sure your array is also sorted by timestamps (as secondary index).

```
function compare(a, b) { return a == b ? 0 : a < b ? -1 : 1;}

function byNameAndTimestamp (a, b) {
    return a[0] == b[0] ? compare(a[1], b[1]) : compare(a[0], b[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Julian, I tried your code above but then my emulator was sorting the dates incorrectly too.  

I then realised that the timestamps have an "at" in them which probably causes issues with the sorting.  

So I converted the timestamp using Date.parse when building the array and now it sorts just fine.  

Thanks for your help.